# Searching for an idiomatic Rust implementation of Minimum Edit Distance (LeetCode #72)

Tags: java, algorithm, rust, dynamic-programming

I am solving LeetCode Dynamic Programming challenges (this one is #72, at https://leetcode.com/problems/edit-distance).

Here below, I've implemented a Rust solution for the minimum edit distance between two strings problem. (Note that this solution works and passes all the test cases on LeetCode)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp::min;

impl Solution {
    pub fn min_distance(word1: String, word2: String) -> i32 {
        let mut D: HashMap<(i32, i32), i32> = HashMap::new();
        let m = word1.len() as i32;
        let n = word2.len() as i32;

        let w1: Vec<char> = word1.chars().collect();
        let w2: Vec<char> = word2.chars().collect();

        for i in 0..=m {
            D.insert((i, 0), i);
        }
        for j in 0..=n {
            D.insert((0, j), j);
        }

        for i in 1..=m {
            for j in 1..=n {
                if w1[(i-1) as usize] == w2[(j-1) as usize] { 
                    D.insert((i, j), *D.get(&(i-1, j-1)).unwrap());
                } else {
                    let p = *D.get(&(i - 1, j - 1)).unwrap();
                    let q = *D.get(&(i - 1, j)).unwrap();
                    let r = *D.get(&(i, j - 1)).unwrap();

                    D.insert((i, j), 1 + min(p, min(q, r)));
                }
            }
        }

        return *D.get(&(m, n)).unwrap();
    }
}
```

I've actually also solved the same thing in JAVA, which I have a much better command on...

```java
public class EditDistance {
    public static int minDistance(String word1, String word2) {
        int m = word1.length();
        int n = word2.length();
        int[][] D = new int[m+1][n+1];

        for(int i=0; i<=m; ++i) D[i][0] = i;
        for(int j=0; j<=n; ++j) D[0][j] = j;

        for(int i=1; i<=m; ++i) {
            for(int j=1; j<=n; ++j) {
                if(word1.charAt(i-1) == word2.charAt(j-1)) D[i][j] = D[i-1][j-1];
                else D[i][j] = 1 + Math.min(D[i-1][j-1], Math.min(D[i-1][j], D[i][j-1]));
            }
        }
        return D[m][n];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(minDistance("intention", "execution"));
    }
}
```

Something about my Rust solution seems off to me. Not really sure but here are some of my irritations:

1. I couldn't find a better way to iterate a string and refer to it by its index easily other than having to convert it to a vector.
2. I think I'm `unwrap()`-ing too much. Although I'm not aiming for code golf here, it still feels subconsciously that I could have avoided so many `unwrap()`s.
3. I feel a bit bad because I kind of word to word translated my solution from Java... perhaps there's a more Rust-idiomatic way of doing whatever I did?

Looking forward to your advise and help :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the Rust implementation pass all the tests on LeetCode?

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes it does! :)

Comment: So, are you looking on a review of both pieces? If yes, then you should split the question. Also, you say "something is off", is it working as expected?

Comment: @Bobby -- I'm primarily looking for the review of the rust implementation, however as a bonus java review will also be welcome. But I'm more interested in the rust review. I provide the java version because I kind of wrote the java solution first and then translated that to rust... I thought that would help create some kind of better "mental model". When I say "something is off", I say it from an idiomatic perspective. The code itself works -- I just felt that the way I did it is potentially more java-like than rust-like? If that's even a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I noticed about both versions of your code is the plenitude of single-letter names, something you can improve upon.  Incidentally, Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, so the compiler would have warned you about `D`.

Now, let's talk about the struggles I presume you have by reading the Rust code.

First of all, you probably felt forced to convert between `i32` and `usize` all the time.  The decision to return `i32` instead of `usize` is a typical indicator of the less-than-ideal quality of LeetCode interfaces (as usual).  In fact, it goes worse - `impl Solution` is not a good idea in Rust, and there is no reason to take the ownership of strings here.  My advice here would be to perform all calculations using `usize` and only convert to `i32` at the very end.

I assume `HashMap<(i32, i32), i32>` results from the lack of multi-dimensional vector support in Rust.  Indeed, my first choice would be to use [`ndarray`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/) in this scenario, which is not available in the standard library.  You can make a small wrapper for this:

```rust
struct Vec2<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>,
    n_rows: usize,
    n_columns: usize,
}
```

and derive `Index<(usize, usize)>` and `IndexMut<(usize, usize)>`.  Or you could sacrifice some performance and use `Vec<Vec<usize>>`.

Instead of

```rust
let w1: Vec<char> = word1.chars().collect();
let w2: Vec<char> = word2.chars().collect();
```

I would simply use `.as_bytes()`, assuming that LeetCode doesn't consider multi-byte characters.

---

Here's how I reassembled everything according to the Java version: (not tested)

```rust
pub fn min_distance(word_a: String, word_b: String) -> i32 {
    let word_a = word_a.as_bytes();
    let word_b = word_b.as_bytes();

    let len_a = word_a.len();
    let len_b = word_b.len();

    let mut matrix = vec![vec![0; len_b + 1]; len_a + 1];

    for i in 0..=len_a {
        matrix[i][0] = i;
    }
    for j in 0..=len_b {
        matrix[0][j] = j;
    }

    for i in 1..=len_a {
        for j in 1..=len_b {
            matrix[i][j] = if word_a[i - 1] == word_b[j - 1] {
                matrix[i - 1][j - 1]
            } else {
                1 + matrix[i - 1][j - 1]
                    .min(matrix[i - 1][j])
                    .min(matrix[i][j - 1])
            };
        }
    }

    matrix[len_a][len_b] as i32
}
```

The restriction of LeetCode (poor interface, no external crates) caused me to be lazy, so I used nested `Vec`s.  In a real-world scenario, `ndarray::Array2` would be a far better choice.

Besides, this is still far from optimal for Rust, where we tend to avoid manual indexing and `- 1`.  Taking into account the algorithmic nature of this application, I won't go deeper into this.

Comment: Such a beautiful review, thank you -- I'll wait a few days before accepting it :-)

Comment: The function signature can be improved to `min_distance(word_a: &str, word_b: &str) -> i32` (it still compiles). You may have intended to change that

Comment: @6005 I would have gone ahead and changed it to `(&str, &str) -> usize` - but the interface is a restriction of LeetCode, so I left it as is.